# Google Docs Script Find and Replace Array Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, arraylist, replace

I am writing a novel in a Google Doc. When complete, it will have probably have in excess of 75 chapters. I am not writing those chapters sequentially. Consequently, I am not attempting to use Chapter numbers, but rather a placeholder of "Chapter_" for each chapter heading (to be used as a search term when I am ready to replace the placeholders).

However, as I get further into the process, I will want to periodically number the chapters sequentially. Rather than do this manually, I would like to be able to automate the process with a Google script.

The following script is almost there, except that it numbers all of the chapters as "Chapter 1." I suspect I need to load an array with the chapter numbers, but despite much research, I can not figure out how to do that.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom')
      .addItem('Renumber Chapters', 'reChapter')
      .addToUi();
}
function reChapter(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  body = doc.getBody();
  var n = 30;
      Logger.log(n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    num = i+1
    newText = "Chapter "+num+"";
    body.replaceText("Chapter_", newText);
  }
}
```

At first, I thought perhaps the loop was not running, but upon checking my log, it is:

```
2:46:16 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:46:16 PM  Info    30.0
2:46:16 PM  Info    0.0
2:46:16 PM  Info    1.0
2:46:16 PM  Info    2.0
2:46:16 PM  Info    3.0
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Note: My starting point for this code was something close, but not quite on point at: [another stackoverflow post/query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967805/find-and-replace-in-a-loop-in-google-docs-app-script)

Just to be clear, rather than the chapters being renumbered as:

```
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
Chapter 3
and so on

They are coming out:
Chapter 1
Chapter 1
Chapter 1
etc.
```

Comment: `body.replaceText()` replaces all occurrences at once (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String))). So, the first loop does all the replacing, and then the remaining loops do nothing. An alternative approach is shown in the answer here: [Google App Script replaceText to replace only first occurrence of matched string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783382/google-app-script-replacetext-to-replace-only-first-occurrence-of-matched-string). In other words, use their "find first" technique in your loop.

Comment: I wanted to add something (which may already be totally obvious): This updating of the `Chapter_` placeholders is a one-shot process. Once the placeholders have gone, then you will need a different script function if you want to renumber your chapters again. I am not too familiar with Google Docs, but... do they not have something built-in which can renumber or sort by chapter headings (based on style types, etc.)?

Comment: @andrewjames-- Thanks a bunch mate. See revised code. Works great. And yes, I realize this was a one-time thing. But rewriting with regex to find "Chapter xxx" (i.e., "Chapter" plus one or more digits) pretty straight forward now that I know how to handle a loop like this. And no, Google Docs does not have such a renumbering protocol. Word does, but I prefer Google Docs for  what I am doing, so this is a real time saver.

Comment: Glad it works. Why don't you post that as an answer, (with an acknowledgement to the other answer)? I think your answer is sufficiently different/extended to stand on its own. (if there was a more exact dupe, I missed it).

Comment: Happy to if you can give me an assist as to how. (I am somewhat new here.)  Do I use the blue "Answer Your Question" button? And is there a formal way to do the acknowledgement?

Comment: Yes - see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Click on that blue button; copy the relevant code from the question to the answer; remove that "answer" code from the question; add any explanations to your answer which you think will _help future visitors_ (that is the main point); add a short sentence to the effect that part of your answer is based on (insert URL link to that other question...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon @andrewjames on-point guidance, I rewrote the script as follows and it works. The [key bit of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783382/google-app-script-replacetext-to-replace-only-first-occurrence-of-matched-string) that made it work came from another discussion here at stackoverflow that @andrewjames brought to my attention (adapted herein in the end of the "reChapter" function and fully in the "replaceIt" function).

```
  function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom')
      .addItem('Renumber Chapters', 'reChapter')
      .addToUi();
}
function reChapter(){
  var n = 30;
  var replaceTerm = "Chapter_"
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    num = i+1
    Logger.log(i);
    newText = "Chapter "+num+"";
    replaceIt(replaceTerm, body);
  }
}
// replaces the occurrences
function replaceIt(replaceTerm, body) {    
  var found = body.findText(replaceTerm);
  if (found) {
   var start = found.getStartOffset();
    var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    var text = found.getElement().asText();
  text.deleteText(start, end);
  text.insertText(start, newText);
  }
}
```